# Intellij do not load project right

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

when I create a new project everything is fine and work well. If I close IntelliJ and open it again, it shows me the recent projects, but if I will load one nothing happened. It only show's me the background of IntelliJ and nothing else. If I open the .IML source IntelliJ load the correct project structure but all "class"-files have the .java ending and IntelliJ find no SDK and so on.

Thanks for helping and if you find any mistakes correct me, please. It's also important to write correct English :)

Comment: Are you projects located under OneDrive: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181356?

Comment: yes, thanks for the help!